# Como calcular total de moedas - java

Tags: java

O programa mostra uma quantidade qualquer de moedas e seus valores. Preciso criar um método publico que faça a soma total de moedas, não estou conseguindo.

```
package primeiro;

public class ControleMoedas {
    private String nomeTitular;
    private int qtde1c;
    private int qtde5c;
    private int qtde10c;
    private int qtde25c;
    private int qtde50c;
    private int qtde1r;

    ///acrescenta as qtde de cada moeda.
    public void depositarMoeda1c(int moeda1c) {
        this.qtde1c += moeda1c;
    }
    public void depositarMoeda5c(int moeda5c) {
        this.qtde1c += moeda5c;
    }
    public void depositarMoeda10c(int moeda10c) {
        this.qtde1c += moeda10c;
    }
    public void depositarMoeda25c(int moeda25c) {
        this.qtde1c += moeda25c;
    }
    public void depositarMoeda50c(int moeda50c) {
        this.qtde1c += moeda50c;
    }
    public void depositarMoeda1r(int moeda1r) {
        this.qtde1c += moeda1r;
    }
    //calcular a qtde total das moedas. TRANCADO AQUI
    public void somarQtdeMoedas(int totalMoedas) {

    }
    //não recebem parâmetros e não retornam valores.
    public String getNomeTitular() {
        return nomeTitular;
    }
    public void setNomeTitular(String nomeTitular) {
        this.nomeTitular = nomeTitular;
    }
    public int getQtde1c() {
        return qtde1c;
    }
    public int getQtde5c() {
        return qtde5c;
    }
    public int getQtde10c() {
        return qtde10c;
    }
    public int getQtde25c() {
        return qtde25c;
    }
    public int getQtde50c() {
        return qtde50c;
    }
    public int getQtde1r() {
        return qtde1r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá @En.Fabiano, boa tarde. Segue uma abordagem possível,

```
package stackoverflow;

public class ControleMoedas {
   private String nomeTitular;
   private int qtde1c;
   private int qtde5c;
   private int qtde10c;
   private int qtde25c;
   private int qtde50c;
   private int qtde1r;

///acrescenta as qtde de cada moeda.
   public void depositarMoeda1c(int moeda1c) {
        this.qtde1c += moeda1c;
   }
   public void depositarMoeda5c(int moeda5c) {
        this.qtde5c += moeda5c;
   }
   public void depositarMoeda10c(int moeda10c) {
       this.qtde10c += moeda10c;
   }
   public void depositarMoeda25c(int moeda25c) {
       this.qtde25c += moeda25c;
   }
   public void depositarMoeda50c(int moeda50c) {
       this.qtde50c += moeda50c;
   }
   public void depositarMoeda1r(int moeda1r) {
      this.qtde1r += moeda1r;
   }

  public int somarQtdeMoedas() {
        return this.getQtde1c() + this.getQtde5c() + this.qtde10c + this.qtde25c + 
        this.qtde50c + this.qtde1r;
  }

  public double somarValorMoedas() {
       return (this.getQtde1c() * 0.01) + (this.getQtde5c() * 0.05) + (this.qtde10c * 0.10) + (this.qtde25c * 0.25) + (this.qtde50c * 0.50) + (this.qtde1r * 1);
}

//não recebem parâmetros e não retornam valores.
   public String getNomeTitular() {
        return nomeTitular;
   }
   public void setNomeTitular(String nomeTitular) {
       this.nomeTitular = nomeTitular;
   }
   public int getQtde1c() {
       return qtde1c;
   }
   public int getQtde5c() {
       return qtde5c;
   }
   public int getQtde10c() {
       return qtde10c;
   }
   public int getQtde25c() {
      return qtde25c;
   }
   public int getQtde50c() {
       return qtde50c;
   }
   public int getQtde1r() {
       return qtde1r;
   }
```

}

Bom, realizei algumas mudanças no código, vi que você estava utilizando um parâmetro para receber o total de moedas, no caso acredito que você queria realiza-lo fora do método, mas, segui a seguinte abordagem, dando o retorno do método para a classe main de um integer com a somatória de todas as moedas no seguinte método. Tomei a liberdade de criar um outro método também, esse que calcula o valor de todas as moedas, para caso queira praticar em algumas mudanças. Bom, é isso, espero ter ajudado! Abraço!

```
public int somarQtdeMoedas() {
    return this.getQtde1c() + this.getQtde5c() + this.qtde10c + this.qtde25c + 
    this.qtde50c + this.qtde1r;
 }


public double somarValorMoedas() {
   return (this.getQtde1c() * 0.01) + (this.getQtde5c() * 0.05) + (this.qtde10c * 0.10) + (this.qtde25c * 0.25) + (this.qtde50c * 0.50) + (this.qtde1r * 1);
}
```

Comment: Ajudou muito!! Atendeu perfeitamente e a outra sugestão tbm.